# Layout problems with Office UI Fabric

Tags: html, office-ui-fabric

[EDIT: updated to focus the issue on the overlaying problem; also edits have been made to the CodePens]
[EDIT2: updated to include details about the method suggested by Mohamed Mansour]

I'm having difficulties designing the layout for an Office UI Fabric React UI.  This is the layout I currently have:

[image]

The goal is to keep the top CommandBar and headers (the text labels and search box) anchored to the top, with the DetailsList and filing button anchored to the bottom and taking up as much space as possible after the header area.

I've successfully used ScrollablePane and two Sticky components to anchor the CommandBar and button in the desired places. However, the DetailsList scrolls through the top Sticky containing the CommandBar and header, and the button is slightly overlayed on top of the DetailsList grid:

[image]

I've tried using the Fabric Grid component to layout all sections but it doesn't make a difference (if it would help at all). The best layout has the projects section in between two Sticky elements; the layout is horrible if the project section is added to either of the Header or Footer Sticky elements.  How can I ensure that the DetailsList doesn't scroll under the top and bottom components?

Here are two code pens that illustrate the issue:

Without Grid: https://codepen.io/elegault/pen/aQayvY?editors=0010 (the fileHeader uses a grid for its elements, but all other elements are not in a grid)

```js
const columns = [{
  key: 'projectNameColumn',
  name: 'Project',
  fieldName: 'name',
  minWidth: 100,
  maxWidth: 200,
  isResizable: true,
  ariaLabel: 'Operations for Project'
}];
const items = [{
    id: '0',
    name: 'ABC Construction'
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Air Bee and Bee'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Architectural Salvage'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Arkham Airport'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    name: 'Arkham Assembly Hall'
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    name: 'Arkham Library'
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'zArkham Renovation'
  },
  {
    id: '7',
    name: 'Foo'
  },
  {
    id: '8',
    name: 'Foo1'
  },
  {
    id: '9',
    name: 'Foo2'
  },
  {
    id: '10',
    name: 'Foo3'
  },
  {
    id: '11',
    name: 'Foo4'
  },
  {
    id: '12',
    name: 'Foo5'
  },
  {
    id: '13',
    name: 'Foo6'
  },
  {
    id: '14',
    name: 'Foo7'
  },
  {
    id: '15',
    name: 'Foo8'
  },
  {
    id: '16',
    name: 'Foo9'
  },
  {
    id: '17',
    name: 'Foo10'
  },
];
class Content extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    const fileHeader = <
      div className = 'ms-Grid' >
      <
      div className = 'ms-Grid-row' >
      <
      div className = 'ms-Grid-col ms-sm2 ms-md2 ms-lg2' >
      <
      img width = '32'
    height = '32'
    alt = 'logo'
    title = 'logo' / >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = 'ms-Grid-col ms-sm10 ms-md10 ms-lg10' >
      <
      Fabric.Label className = 'ms-font-l ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontColor-blue' > [TITLE] < /Fabric.Label> <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      div className = 'ms-Grid-row' >
      <
      div className = 'ms-Grid-col ms-sm2 ms-md2 ms-lg2' >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = 'ms-Grid-col ms-sm10 ms-md10 ms-lg10' >
      <
      Fabric.Label
    className = 'ms-font-m ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary' > SELECTED PROJECT: < /Fabric.Label> <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /div>;

    const commandBar = < div >
      <
      Fabric.CommandBar
    isSearchBoxVisible = {
      false
    }
    items = {
      [{
        key: 'openWebApp',
        name: 'Open Web App',
        icon: 'OpenInNewWindow', // Or Link
        ['data-automation-id']: 'openWebAppButton',
        title: 'Open web app',
        href: 'http://www.codepen.io',
        target: '_blank',
      }]
    }
    farItems = {
      [{
        key: 'menuOptions',
        name: 'Options',
        icon: 'Settings',
        iconOnly: 'true',
        ['data-automation-id']: 'settingsButton',
        subMenuProps: {
          items: [{
              key: 'privacyPolicy',
              name: 'Privacy Policy',
              icon: 'PageLock',
              href: 'http://www.codepen.io',
              target: '_blank',

            },
            {
              key: 'termsOfUse',
              name: 'Terms & Conditions',
              icon: 'TextDocument',
              href: 'http://www.codepen.io',
              target: '_blank'
            }
          ]
        }
      }]
    }
    /> <
    /div>;

    const projects = < Fabric.MarqueeSelection selection = {
      null
    }
    data - is - scrollable = {
        false
      } >
      <
      Fabric.DetailsList
    items = {
      items
    }
    columns = {
      columns
    }
    /> <
    /Fabric.MarqueeSelection>;
    const selection = < div > [project name] < /div>;
    const search = < Fabric.TextField label = 'Search projects:' / > ;
    const fileButton = <
      div >
      <
      Fabric.DefaultButton primary = {
        true
      } > File To Project < /Fabric.DefaultButton> <
      /div>;

    return ( <
      Fabric.Fabric >
      <
      div style = {
        {
          height: '500px',
          position: 'relative',
          maxHeight: 'inherit'
        }
      } >
      <
      Fabric.ScrollablePane scrollbarVisibility = {
        Fabric.ScrollbarVisibility.auto
      } >
      <
      Fabric.Sticky stickyPosition = {
        Fabric.StickyPositionType.Header
      } > {
        commandBar
      } {
        fileHeader
      } {
        selection
      } {
        search
      } <
      /Fabric.Sticky>     {
        projects
      } <
      Fabric.Sticky stickyPosition = {
        Fabric.StickyPositionType.Footer
      } > {
        fileButton
      } <
      /Fabric.Sticky>       <
      /Fabric.ScrollablePane> <
      /div> <
      /Fabric.Fabric>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Content / > ,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

With full Grid: https://codepen.io/elegault/pen/wQxoRR

```js
const columns = [
    {
        key: 'projectNameColumn',
        name: 'Project',
        fieldName: 'name',
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true,
        ariaLabel: 'Operations for Project'
    }
];
const items = [
    {id: '0', name: 'ABC Construction'},
    {id: '1', name: 'Air Bee and Bee'},
    {id: '2', name: 'Architectural Salvage'},
    {id: '3', name: 'Arkham Airport'},
    {id: '4', name: 'Arkham Assembly Hall'},
    {id: '5', name: 'Arkham Library'},
    {id: '6', name: 'zArkham Renovation'},
    {id: '7', name: 'Foo'},
    {id: '8', name: 'Foo1'},
    {id: '9', name: 'Foo2'},
    {id: '10', name: 'Foo3'},
    {id: '11', name: 'Foo4'},
    {id: '12', name: 'Foo5'},
    {id: '13', name: 'Foo6'},
    {id: '14', name: 'Foo7'},
    {id: '15', name: 'Foo8'},
    {id: '16', name: 'Foo9'},
    {id: '17', name: 'Foo10'},
];
class Content extends React.Component {
    public render() {        
        
  const commandBar = <div>
            <Fabric.CommandBar
                isSearchBoxVisible={false}
                items={[
                    {
                        key: 'openWebApp',
                        name: 'Open Web App',
                        icon: 'OpenInNewWindow', // Or Link                        
                        title: 'Open web app',
                        href: 'http://www.codepen.io',
                        target: '_blank',
                    }
                ]}
                farItems={[
                    {
                        key: 'menuOptions',
                        name: 'Options',
                        icon: 'Settings',
                        iconOnly: 'true',
                        ['data-automation-id']: 'settingsButton',
                        subMenuProps: {
                            items: [
                                {
                                    key: 'privacyPolicy',
                                    name: 'Privacy Policy',
                                    icon: 'PageLock',
                                    href: 'http://www.codepen.io',
                                    target: '_blank',

                                },
                                {
                                    key: 'termsOfUse',
                                    name: 'Terms & Conditions',
                                    icon: 'TextDocument',
                                    href: 'http://www.codepen.io',
                                    target: '_blank'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]}
            />
        </div>;
      
        const projects = <Fabric.MarqueeSelection selection={null} data-is-scrollable={false}>
            <Fabric.DetailsList
                items={items}
                columns={columns}              
            />
        </Fabric.MarqueeSelection>;
        const selection = <div>[project name]</div>;
        const search = <Fabric.TextField label='Search projects:'/>;
        const fileButton = 
              <div>
                <Fabric.DefaultButton primary={true}>File To Project</Fabric.DefaultButton>
              </div>;
  
      const fileHeader =             
            <div className='ms-Grid'>
                <div className='ms-Grid-row'>
                    <div className='ms-Grid-col ms-sm2 ms-md2 ms-lg2'>
                        <img width='32' height='32' alt='logo' title='logo'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='ms-Grid-col ms-sm10 ms-md10 ms-lg10'>
                        <Fabric.Label className='ms-font-l ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontColor-blue'>[TITLE]</Fabric.Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='ms-Grid-row'>
                    <div className='ms-Grid-col ms-sm2 ms-md2 ms-lg2'>
                    </div>
                    <div className='ms-Grid-col ms-sm10 ms-md10 ms-lg10'>
                        <Fabric.Label
                            className='ms-font-m ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary'>SELECTED PROJECT:</Fabric.Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>;
   
        return (
   <Fabric.Fabric>                
    <div style={{height:'500px', position:'relative', maxHeight:'inherit'}}>          
          <Fabric.ScrollablePane scrollbarVisibility={Fabric.ScrollbarVisibility.auto}>
      <div className='ms-Grid'>
       <Fabric.Sticky stickyPosition={Fabric.StickyPositionType.Header}>
        <div className='ms-Grid-row'>
         <div className='ms-Grid-col ms-sm10 ms-md10 ms-lg10'>
          {commandBar}
         </div>
        </div>        
        <div className='ms-Grid-row'>
         <div className='ms-Grid-col ms-sm10 ms-md10 ms-lg10'>
          {fileHeader}
         </div>
        </div>         
        <div className='ms-Grid-row'>
         <div className='ms-Grid-col ms-sm10 ms-md10 ms-lg10'>
          {selection}
         </div>
        </div>       
        <div className='ms-Grid-row'>
         <div className='ms-Grid-col ms-sm10 ms-md10 ms-lg10'>
          {search}            
         </div>
        </div>                  
       </Fabric.Sticky>    
       <div className='ms-Grid-row'>
        <div className='ms-Grid-col ms-sm10 ms-md10 ms-lg10'>
         {projects}            
        </div>
       </div>                              
       <Fabric.Sticky stickyPosition={Fabric.StickyPositionType.Footer}>      
        <div className='ms-Grid-row'>
         <div className='ms-Grid-col ms-sm10 ms-md10 ms-lg10'>
          {fileButton}            
         </div>
        </div>        
       </Fabric.Sticky>      
      </div>
          </Fabric.ScrollablePane>
    </div>
      </Fabric.Fabric>
        );   
  
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Content />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Also, when attempting to use Flex classes or defined heights in parent divs (as per Mohamed Mansour's suggestion) in a project outside of the codepens that uses nested custom React components, the entire DetailsList fails to render. For example, this DOM explorer shows how even setting a defined height and using flex in multiple 'main' divs still fails to render DetailsList:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets clear some terminology, these are from the docs:

- **[ScrollablePane](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/scrollablepane)**: Uses absolute positioning, the parent has to have relative and a height (either from flex or static). So if you want it to stretch in your own way, you need to satisfy these constraints.
- **Sticky**:  These are ideally for headers and footers, but will still be within the scrollbar region. Usually used for multiple section.
- **Overlapping Contents**: This is perfectly normal, your header and footer do not have a solid background, set it to white, and it will work as expected.

To achieve what you wanted, for the scrollbar to just appear between the header and footer, you could add some normal CSS. Run the snippet below to see it. Basically just a flex layout.

I have updated your example as well: https://codepen.io/mohamedhmansour/pen/rQqqvP

```js
let { DetailsList, Fabric, ScrollablePane, ScrollbarVisibility } = window.Fabric;

function Content() {
  const items = [...Array(500).keys()].map(i => ({key: i, text: `Item ${i}`}));
  
  return (
    <ScrollablePane  scrollbarVisibility={ScrollbarVisibility.auto}> 
      <DetailsList items={items} />
    </ScrollablePane>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Fabric className='wrapper'>
    <div className='header'>Header</div>
    <div className='main'>
      <Content />
    </div>
    <div className='footer'>Footer</div>
  </Fabric>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}


.header, .footer {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<!-- could point to local version -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/office-ui-fabric-react.min.js"></script>

<div id='content'></div>
```

Comment: This is most excellent - thanks for the guidance, much appreciated!

Comment: Although this layout works perfectly in both of our CodePens, there's a strange issue when it is implemented in my add-in. Basically the entire DetailsList element doesn't get rendered at all!!! If I remove the containing ScrollablePane element, then it gets rendered. The TypeScript code that loads the projects and sets the state works the same in both situations. Do you have any ideas how ScrollablePane could be breaking this somehow??

Comment: I've narrowed it down further - the problem is how my app is using multiple nested React components. Eg. <App><MyUI><MyAppProjectList><ProjectList><DetailsList>... where ProjectList is where the <div id='main'> element contains the DetailsList. I have to use main in App in order to get this to work. Each child of App has a root <div>, so these multiple divs is breaking things somehow

Comment: @EricLegault when it can't render, it basically means there is a height missing. Look at all the parents up to html to see if a height is defined. Easy way doing this, is in the inspector, look if it is highlighting the height. In the codepen, I made sure the height is full page. Does your App/MyUI/MyAppProjectList/ProjectList have full height

Comment: Okay I'll check. But I was inspecting the rendered HTML in your codepen and couldn't find any defined heights. Which div/block should have the height? Is it okay to have multiple heights defined?

Comment: @EricLegault the heights were done by using `FlexLayout` the first '.wrapper' uses absolute positioning to fill the entire screen including setting it to flex. The inner divs, then finally the main div has `flex: 1` which means it will fill and stretch as well its position is `relative`. And once you place the `ScrollablePane` within that region, it respects the `relative` positioning, and fills up that entire div.

Comment: See the screenshot of the inspector that I added at the end of my question. I added a defined height to app-ProjectList (and main to its parent) and it still doesn't work (same with switching app-ProjectList to main). No other elements have a defined height except for body. The selection square is the deepest level component (so App -> AppUI -> ProjectList)

Comment: Not sure if this is related to my ongoing issues, but I wasn't using a function to return the ScrollablePane and DetailsList components the way you are with the <Content /> block and Content() function, or if that's related to document.getElementById('content')